# Replace multiple values with different values php

Tags: php

```
<?php
$status = '@abc are @cde and @fgh';
$values = array("@valuesA", "@valuesB", "@valuesC");
echo $status = preg_replace_callback("/(\s+|^)@\S+/", function($matches) use ($values) { return $values[array_rand($values)]; }, $status);
?>
```

How can i replace with different value without repeated value,
i want the output like this: "@valuesA are @valuesB and @valuesC"
in sequence

Comment: what???? seriously.....what is the question?

Comment: @KyleK replace `@abc @cde and @fgh` with `@valuesa, @valuesb and @valuesc` respectively. It shoud be done with `str_replace` - not with regex

Comment: in fact its randomly, sometime occur with same value. how can the result is in sequence.

Comment: if it's static why not just use sprintf instead of creating your own bastardised version of it?

Comment: it's like twitter account or email, initially with "at sign" and a dynamic value

Answer (score 0):

```
$status = '@abc are @cde and @fgh';
$a1 = array('@abc', '@cde', '@fgh');
$a2 = array('@valuesA', '@valuesB', '@valuesC');

$new_status = str_replace($a1 , $a2 , $status );
```

It's really easy with `str_replace`, just map the original values and the replacement values.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use `shuffle`. This way, the number of values stays the same, and there will be no repetitions.

```
$status = '@abc are @cde and @fgh';
$values = array("@valuesA", "@valuesB", "@valuesC");

shuffle($values);
```

Even better with simple string replacement:

```
$xlat = array(
    '@abc'   => $valueA,
    '@cde'   => $valueB,
...);

$result = str_replace(array_keys($xlat),
                      shuffle(array_values($xlat)),
                      $status);
```

(I initially believed this could be done implementing the Durstenfeld algorithm or "*Knuth's Shuffle*", but this requires maintaining a *state* vector of the same size as the initial `$values` vector. So, while it *could* be done - [here's how](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Modern_method) -, it would actually be *less* efficient than the in-place version).

Answer (score 0):

It really seems like you're trying to create your own version of sprintf:

```
$status = '%s are %s and %s';
$new_status = sprintf($status, '@valuesA', '@valuesB', '@valuesC');
echo $new_status;
```